# How to limit the memory used by a process using psutil?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, psutil

I was wondering how to limit the memory used by a process created using `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` and it should also detect if the process uses more memory than allotted.

Preferably I am looking for a solution using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/2.2.1). I am using python 3.4 in windows 7.

Comment: I have not much experience in this, but I think, the `resource`-module might be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/resource.html

Comment: It is unix specific. I want something that works on windows.